# java mongoDB queries not working when DB version upgraded

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mongodb-query

i am using spring mvc and database is mongoDB 4.0.1 version All aggregation queries are working but normal simple quires are not working like below query.

```
Query q=new Query(Criteria.where("userID").is("1"));
User dbuser=    mongotemplate.findOne(q, User.class,"User");
```

previously i am using mongoDB 3.2 version some of the aggregation queries are not working so i switched to new version 4.0.1 and the following dependency version upgraded from  `<version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>` to 2.0.3

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting the following error

```
  [http-bio-8080-exec-11] INFO org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:215}] to localhost:27017
Aug 11, 2018 8:46:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [myServlet] in context with path [/CitiTwo] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.getPropertyAccessor(BasicPersistentEntity.java:427)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:276)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:253)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:202)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2775)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2392)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:2184)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:720)
    at com.citizenchat.daoImpl.SearchFiltersDaoImpl.defaultnearby(SearchFiltersDaoImpl.java:302)
    at com.citizenchat.controller.SearchFiltersController.defaultnearby(SearchFiltersController.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

so i switched from spring maven to spring boot gradle project same issue i am getting normal simple queries are not working but aggregation queries are working.

my dependencies in spring boot gradle project are below

```
 dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '26.0-jre'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'

}
```

so any one pls help me.Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

If you are using org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:2.0.3.RELEASE it means you are using MongoDB Java driver 3.5.0, you can check the above dependency [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb-parent/2.0.3.RELEASE). Looking at the compatibility between MongoDB Java driver versions and MongoDB databases, you can check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#java-driver-compatibility) that MongoDB Java driver 3.5.0 is not compatible with MongoDB 4.0

So I suggest you to downgrade your database deployment to MongoDB 3.4.